# sum of datetime.datetime object gave an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, list, datetime, sum, timedelta

I'm trying to sum a list of datetime.datetime object using :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
d= [datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 1, 9, 31, 24), datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 11, 17, 22, 18), datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 3, 16, 6, 59)]

sum_d = sum(d, timedelta())
```

I get the error :

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'`

any idea what am I doing wrong or how I can sum up this list?

I want to get the average of this list I was thinking about:

```
 d_avg = sum(d, timedelta()) / len(d)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's simply because you can't add times. You can add time *deltas*, but not times themselves.

I mean, what is 3<sup>rd</sup> Aug 1995 + 19<sup>th</sup> June 454? It doesn't make sense. You can add the distance from Year 0 but that's different to adding the dates themselves.

What do you hope to get from this calculation?

---

If you hope to find the mean (why?), you'll have to use a less direct route

```
import datetime

d = [datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 1, 9, 31, 24), datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 11, 17, 22, 18), datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 3, 16, 6, 59)]

d[0] + sum((d_i-d[0] for d_i in d), datetime.timedelta(0)) / len(d)
#>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 5, 22, 20, 13, 666667)
```

This finds the sum of offsets from `d[0]`, means *those* and then adds that offset back on.

Comment: Average of those dates, will be great to get it as timedelta object.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot sum this list:  as the error message said, `datetime.datetime` objects cannot be added.  What on Earth, for example, would you expect `datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 1, 9, 31, 24), datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 11, 17, 22, 18)` to return?  Python generally won't do things that make no sense at all ;-)